# How to use loop to get every element?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, loops, for-loop

```py
def get_first_profile_id(service):
    # Use the Analytics service object to get the first profile id.

    # Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for this user
    accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()

    if accounts.get('items'):
        # Get the first Google Analytics account.
        account = accounts.get('items')[0].get('id')

        # Get a list of all the properties for the first account.
        properties = service.management().webproperties().list(
                accountId=account).execute()

        if properties.get('items'):
            # Get the first property id.
            property = properties.get('items')[0].get('id')

            # Get a list of all views (profiles) for the first property.
            profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
                    accountId=account,
                    webPropertyId=property).execute()

            if profiles.get('items'):
                # return the first view (profile) id.
                return profiles.get('items')[0].get('id')

    return None
```

Hi folks, I am using Google Analytics API to extract the data using Python. Above is the sample code provided by Google.

I want to use loops to extract every "view (profile) id" from each property under each account. However, the code above only extracted the first view (profile) id of the first property of the first account.

Can you share any suggestions? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) for xxx.get('items')[0] to loop through all items in account/properties/profiles. Append the profile in a list and return result after all loops.

```py
def get_first_profile_id(service):
    # Use the Analytics service object to get the first profile id.

    # Get a list of all Google Analytics accounts for the authorized user.
    accounts = service.management().accounts().list().execute()

    if accounts.get('items'):
        result = []
        # Loop through Google Analytics account.
        for account_item in  accounts.get('items'):
            account = account_item.get('id')
            # Get a list of all the properties for the account.
            properties = service.management().webproperties().list(
                accountId=account).execute()

            if properties.get('items'):
                # Loop through property id.
                for property_item in  properties.get('items'):
                    property = property_item.get('id')

                    # Get a list of all views (profiles) for the property.
                    profiles = service.management().profiles().list(
                        accountId=account,
                        webPropertyId=property).execute()

                    if profiles.get('items'):
                        # append all view (profile) id in result list.
                        for profile_item in profiles.get('items'):
                            result.append(profile_item.get('id'))
        return result
    return None
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if profiles.get('items'):
 # return the first view (profile) id.    
    return profiles.get('items')[0].get('id')
```

with

```
if profiles.get('items'):
 # return the first view (profile) id.    
    return [x.get('id') for x in profiles.get('items')]
```

Comment: Thank you @abhilb. Does your code return all "view (profile) ids" for the first property of the first account?  Should I also update somewhere in "property" and "account"?

Comment: Yes, I think so

Comment: So...How can I get every "view (profile) ids" for all properties of all the accounts?

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to provide a more readable solution for a beginner (not using list comprehension).

```
if profiles.get('items'):
    result = [] 
    for profile in profiles.get('items'):
        result.append(profile.get('id'))
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you @Pitto. Same questions...Does the code return all "view (profile) ids" for the first property of the first account? Should I also update somewhere in "property" and "account"?

Comment: Hi! Please provide you input and expected output so I can help better.